# Apache WAMP connection issue. The pipe has been ended. : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent

Tags: apache, wamp

I recently installed UniServer and i am having problems connecting to Apache. This is the error in the error log:

```
    (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent
    AH00427: Parent: child process 10828 exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

I have tried disabling stopping "Web Deployment Agent Service"and "World Wide Web Publishing Service" but still having the same error.

I have also tried freeing up port 80 but still no change in the error.

When i try and load my page it reads:
 "Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

I have been googling for 2 days now trying to resolve this issue to no resolution.

Any help and suggestions on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it after hours of researching!  I Had to change my config file and change port to port 81. And servername to localhost:81.